# Updating existing property in CoreData fails

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-data

I have a `Job` Model in CoreData and within this object I have values like `job_id` and `start_date` and a one-to-many relation to `JobImage` which is also a CoreData Model.

If I create a new `Job` object and save it together with some `Images`, everything works well. This looks like that:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Job", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
job = Job(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
job?.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "start_date")
job?.setValue(true, forKey: "running")
if let id = jobJson.id {
    job?.setValue(id, forKey: "job_id")
}

do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
} catch {
    print("Something unexpected happened...")
}
```

and adding images like that:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let jpegImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("JobImage", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

let imageObject = JobImage(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
imageObject.data = jpegImage
imageObject.job = job

do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
} catch {
    print("Something unexpected happened...")
}
```

where `job` is the `Job` object which I created earlier (I saved it in the global variable like that `job = Job(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)`) and image is just a UIImage.
The `JobImage` object has a `data` property which is "Binary Data".
I set the `job` property which is the relation to my `Job` object to `job` and save the result.

Everything I mentioned until now works great but if I don't create a new entity but I fetch an existing one and try to add a relation to a new `JobImage` and save the result, it fails. Fetching the object works great, I can access all the properties stored within the `Job` object but saving another image to the `images` relation fails.
I fetch the `Job` object like that:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Job")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "running == true")

do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    let jobs = results as! [Job]
    if jobs.count > 0 {
        job = jobs[0]
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
} catch {
    print("Something unexpected happened...")
}
```

Again, I store the `Job` object in my global property `job` and use it to create new relations to images and save them as before but this time it fails with the following error:

> Could not save Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject= (entity: Job; id: 0xd000000000040000

...

> NSValidationErrorValue: Relationship 'job_images' on managed object (0x7fb094029f10)  (entity: Job; id: 0xd000000000040000

...

> NSValidationErrorKey: job_images, NSLocalizedDescription: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)]

Where `job_images` is my relation from `Job` to `JobImage`.

I read through some StackOverflow questions with `Cocoa error 1550` but none of the answers seem to work for my problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `The operation couldn’t be completed` happens often if a property has no value but is supposed to have one.

Comment: Why are you using a global? Are you reconnecting an existing image to your fetched job? You didn't show that code, but you did show a mass of code that works...

Comment: @Wain As I said, saving the image is exactly the same as shown above, the only difference is how I create the `Job` object, it works well if I create a new one but fails if I fetch an existing one. Saving the image is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: @vadian I read that in some StackOverflow question but this is not the case in my example because I do the exact same thing in both cases but fetching an existing entity and saving a new `JobImage` to it fails.

Comment: Show the code where the error happens - maybe something is slightly different there.

Comment: @sschale There is nothing different, it is the exact same method which is executed, the only difference is how the `Job` object is created first.

Comment: @sschale Setting the image is the second piece of code in my question

Comment: Tell us about your non-optional settings and deletion rules

Comment: @Wain All the properties are optional and the deletion rules are "Nullify" for all relations. Also the relations are optional.

Comment: Unique constraints? You're getting some validation error so what validation is running?

Comment: @Wain Thank you for your help, after I have deleted the entity and recreated it, it worked as expected, but I don't know why and how, I have done the exact same thing again.